# Remove two chars in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, web

I can't remove two symbols in a JS array.

```
var specString = '${s}';
var specialists = specString.split(',');
for(i = 0; i < specialists.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = specialists[i];
    option.text = specialists[i];
    category.appendChild(option);
}

specString = [A,B,C];
```

And when I adding option value, `specialist[0] = '[A'`, next row `'B'` and last`'C]'`. I need just `'A'` and `'C'`, without these `'[]'` symbols.

I tried all JS methods `substr(0;-1), substr(0;specString.length-1), slice` and others.

p.s. `'${s}'` -> this `List<String>` from requestScope

Comment: `specString=specString.substr(1,specString.length-2)` before `specialists=...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your specString is some thing like this:

```
'[A', 'B', 'C]'
```

It must be this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

But you can fix this by:

```
option.value = specialists[i].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Comment: i understand, so i want to remove '[ ]'

Comment: `option.value = specialists[i].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");` will remove.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var specialists = ['A','B','C'];
for(i = 0; i < specialists.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = specialists[i];
    option.text = specialists[i];
    category.appendChild(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply remove single quotes of $a, and your code will run perfectly.

```
var specialists = $a;
```